# adding PushPlugin to CCA project breaks the build

Tags: android, cordova, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, google-chrome-app

I have a chrome-packaged-app project, I want to use a cordova plugin that supports cloud messaging for both android, through the GCM api and iOS through the APN api (this is required as chrome.gcm currently supports only android I believe)

This seems to be a possible solution: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/

So I ran:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
cca run android
```

But I get errors during the build:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

Should there be any problems installing third party cordova plugins within a CCA project?